# ASP.NET SQL datasource combine two queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am currently working on a project for my University Degree using ASP.NET webforms with C#. We are tasked with creating a student information system. I am trying to select from the database information about the student and also about who their advisor of studies is. I can get the ID of the advisor of studies, but I then need to select from the user table twice to get the name of the student and the advisor of studies.
I am making use of an SQL datasource to populate boundfields in a gridview.
Below I have 2 SQL statements which I need to somehow combine into 1.

First select to get the name of the advisor of studies (UserId is known from the cookie of the logged in user):

```
SELECT aos.Forename as StaffForename, aos.Surname as StaffSurname, sdt.AdvisorStudiesID 
FROM [User] aos, [StudentDetails] sdt 
WHERE (sdt.StudentId=@UserId) AND (aos.UserId=sdt.AdvisorStudiesID);
```

Second select to get the name and details of the student:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Forename as StudentForename, Surname as StudentSurname, TitleLong, PersonalTutor, ProfileImage 
FROM [User] u, [StudentDegree] sd, [Degree] d  
WHERE (u.UserId=@UserId) AND (d.DegreeId=sd.DegreeId) AND (sd.StudentId=@UserId);
```

I had tried just separating these queries with a colon in the SQL datasource, but that did not work(see below)

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Student" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ 
ConnectionStrings:QSIS_Connection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT aos.Forename 
as StaffForename, aos.Surname as StaffSurname, sdt.AdvisorStudiesID FROM 
[User] aos, [StudentDetails] sdt WHERE (sdt.StudentId=@UserId) AND 
(aos.UserId=sdt.AdvisorStudiesID); SELECT DISTINCT Forename as 
StudentForename, Surname as StudentSurname, TitleLong, PersonalTutor, 
ProfileImage FROM [User] u, [StudentDegree] sd, [Degree] d  WHERE 
(u.UserId=@UserId) AND (d.DegreeId=sd.DegreeId) AND 
(sd.StudentId=@UserId);"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check out `JOIN`.

Comment: @JacobH I have used JOIN in the past, just not entirely sure how to make it work for this example. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can "Join" more than once.  select student.ForeName, advisor.ForeName from [user] student join [user] advisor on student.AdvisorStudiesID = advisor.StudentId

Comment: If you could write the tables structure. I would write something helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use User table twice in the same query, something like this should do it:

```
SELECT adv.Forename as StaffForename, 
       adv.Forename as StaffSurname, 
       usr.Forename as StudentForename,...etc
usr.Surname  as StudentSurname 
from   User usr, 
       User adv, 
       StudentDetails sdt, 
       StudentDegree sd, 
       Degree d 
where  ( sdt.StudentId = @UserId ) 
       AND ( adv.UserId = sdt.AdvisorStudiesID ) 
       AND ( sdt.StudentId = usr.StudentId)
       AND ( sd.StudentId = usr.StudentId ) 
       AND ( d.DegreeId = sd.DegreeId )
```

Comment: Thanks @AMINCHAR based off your example I came up with the following
    
SELECT s.Forename, s.Surname, s.PersonalTutor, s.ProfileImage, ad.Forename as StaffForename, ad.Surname as StaffSurname, d.TitleLong, sdt.AdvisorStudiesID FROM [User] s, [User] ad, [StudentDetails] sdt, [StudentDegree] sd, [Degree] dWHERE (s.UserId=@UserId) AND (ad.UserId = sdt.AdvisorStudiesID )  AND (sdt.StudentId=s.UserId) AND (d.DegreeId=sd.DegreeId) AND (sd.StudentId=sdt.StudentId)"

Answer (score 0):

```
You seem to have 4 tables
Please try something like this

SELECT col1.Table1, col2.Table1,col1.Table2
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 on Table1.UserID = Table2.ID
INNER JOIN Table3 on Table2.KeyColumn1 = Table3.KeyColumn2
INNER JOIN Table4 on Table3.KeyColumn3 = Table4.KeyColumn4
WHERE <<Clause here>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for a self join.. I am not sure about the exact table structure but based on what you are trying to achieve, I think something like this should work:

```
SELECT student.Forename as StudentForename, student.Surname as StudentSurname, student.TitleLong, student.ProfileImage, advisor.Forename as StaffForename, advisor.Surname as StaffSurname
FROM [StudentDetails] as sdetails
INNER JOIN [User] as student
  ON sdetails.StudentId = student.UserId
INNER JOIN [StudentDegree] as sdegree
  ON sdetails.StudentId = sdegree.StudentId
INNER JOIN [Degree] as degree
  ON sdegree.DegreeId = d.DegreeId
INNER JOIN [User] as advisor
  ON sdetails.AdvisorStudiesID = advisor.UserId
WHERE (sdetails.StudentId=@UserId)
```